# how to center form using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just learned bootstrap and try to centered a form using bootstrap 4 but seems keep failing. I've try put container, margin auto, grid, etc but still failing.

Here is the last code using bootstrap grid.

```
<form class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Example input">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/artjia/emsw7t93/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> used [justify-content-center](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <form class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 ">
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Example input">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
     </span>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Here's a link to v4.3 docs: [Horizontal Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

Comment: the code snippet is not totally correct because offset-lg-3 doesn t exist anymore in bootstrap V4.
More over a container should wrap a 'row' and a row should have direct 'col' children.
Look my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560435/1152632 for a correct bootstrap code (I was the first answer too :) )

Comment: row inside of col?!?

Answer (score 4):

Use the css class `justify-content-center`.
offset-col-* css class doesn t exist anymore in V4 bootstrap. Now it uses flex grid.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
     <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Example input">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
      </span>
     </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info, consult the documentation =>
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Et voilà.

Answer (score 1):

1. Columns go inside rows, not the other way around
2. The offset properties are from Bootstrap 3 not Bootstrap 4. [You should use margin offsets instead](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)

Such:

```
<form class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
```